# Visual Studio executes the old code even after getting the latest version from TFS

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, tfs

Recently I have faced a weird issue with Visual Studio. Every time I get the latest source from TFS, even though the source code gets updated but when I run my project, the old source code is executed!

No matter I clean and rebuild all the solution, I need to close the solution and re-open it to get it to work.

I am using Visual Studio 2012 Update 3 and TFS 2010.

Any idea about this issue?

Comment: Did you just get latest version or get specific version (type = latest)? I've had issues with VS/TFS in the past where I'd get latest version but it wouldn't actually be the latest version. However, I thought that VS2012 improved the 'get latest version' issue.

Comment: I get the latest version both from Solution Explorer and Source Control Explorer but nothing changes.

Comment: Is the content of files 'latest', if yes then check whatever your visual studio doesnt have your code assemblies loaded from somewhere else like GAC, you can use new instance of VS to debug other one and view loaded modules. If answear is no then get specific version with latest and both options selected(maybe changed in VS2012 - basically delete and overwrite). If that doesnt help you might have an issue with VS or TFS cache.

Comment: @drk I think problem is due to VS or TFS cache.

Comment: Have you tried going to Advanced > Get Specific Version and checking "Overwrite writeable files that are not checked out" and "Overwrite all files even if the local version matches the specified version"?

Comment: @ChrisHarris I did it and not a chance. I am going to remove the VS and install it again. May be that can resolve the issue.

Comment: @Morteza Can you right click on your solution in Solution Explorer and select "Open Folder in File Explorer". Then make sure that the directory is the same one mapped to source control?

Comment: @ChrisHarris Of course it is. As I mentioned in the question, everything works like a charm when I close the solution and open it again.